# Bluemix IoT service: Limit on number of applications bound to it

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I am getting below error when trying to bind an application to IoTF service. The binding is successful when I unbind service from another app and then bind the service to this app. But with service already bound to 4 apps, I get this error when I try to bind the service to 5th app. I was not able to see such a constraint mentioned in documentation of IoT service. Hence just wanted to check if this is something I have overlooked somewhere or is this a bug in the service or in the documentation. If yes to latter is this already logged and has a resolution ETA?

> *Error: status code: 502, error code: 10001, message: Service broker error: {"description"=>"Sorry, the IoTF service was unable to process your request."}*

Answer (score 0):

IoTF now Internet of Things Platform has these constraints for free plan:

> - Includes up to 20 active devices, 100 MB of data traffic and 1 GB of
> - storage Free Maximum of 20 active devices
> - Maximum of 100 MB data exchanged
> - Maximum of 1 GB data storage (with 30 day expiry)
> - Maximum of 10 application bindings

In your case seems that you are facing the error when you bind the 5th application that is not included in constraint list. 
In order to do a deep investigation you should open a new ticket
 you open a ticket via one of the two following options which allow you to request a severity for your support request:

The **Support Widget** - this is available from the user avatar in the upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch, then select the type of assistance you need and fill out the support form.

The Support Site '**Get Help**' form - a separate site is made available for ticket submission for cases when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.